# iOS Push Notification Display

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, swift3

Is there a way of knowing if the device is about to display any notification from within an app.

These notifications can be from anywhere, required to create an action from within, for example pause a game.

Answer (score 0):

Your appdelegate's [applicationWillResignActive](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622950-applicationwillresignactive) method gets called when your app is "interrupted" including phone calls and notifications. The documentation actually says this is where you should pause your game. ApplicationDidEnterBackground only gets called if they actually accept the notification or call.

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for your quick answer, I have tried the above and the delegate is not being called